# Gradleエラー：Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

久しぶりにコードの修正をしようと思いましたが、開発環境やプラグインなど環境をアップデートしたら、下記のエラーではまってしまいました。

どこでなにが原因でコンパイルできなくなっているのか、全く見当がつかず、色々調べながら一月ほどはまっています。
他に必要な情報があれば追記しますので、助けていただけないでないでしょうか。

使用環境は
・MAC
・Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1・
・Flutter 3.19.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7482962148 (7 days ago) • 2024-02-27 16:51:22 -0500
Engine • revision 04817c99c9
Tools • Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1
・Java21

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SOG10 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8-5-bin.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Retrying Gradle Build: #1, wait time: 100ms
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8-5-bin.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もしかしたら、以下ファイルのdistributionUrlの記述間違い。

android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

開いてgradle-8-5-bin.zipをgradle-8.5-bin.zipにして見る。

gradle-wrapper.propertiesがない場合は別原因かも。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり、ドットとハイフンの記載ミスが原因でした。